# Java transparent JPanel (allwaysOnTop) triggers Taskbar

Tags: java, jpanel, windows-10, game-development

I recently wrote a program in Java, that functions as a game-overlay (in order to create custom gamemodes in games like Rainbow Six: Siege) by applying the following settings:

```
clientFrame = new JFrame("Window");
clientFrame.setSize(400, 300);

clientFrame.setUndecorated(true);
clientFrame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
clientFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

clientPanel = new JPanel();
clientPanel.setOpaque(false);

textArea_Messages = new JTextArea();
textArea_Messages.setEditable(false);
textArea_Messages.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
textArea_Messages.setFont(font);

clientPanel.add(textArea_Messages);

clientFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, clientPanel);

clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
clientFrame.setVisible(true);
clientFrame.pack();
```

This worked for me the last few months. I had to run the game in borderless window mode in order to display the panel on top of my game, but I was able to Alt+Tab out of the game to change some gamemode settings and reentering it by clicking inside the game window. My JPanel stayed allways on top, and the taskbar disappeared while playing.
Today I noticed that the taskbar doesn't hide anymore. Either it stays on top together with my JPanel, or the JPanel (and the taskbar) aren't visible. I've searched online for hours trying to solve this issue and tested everything (Repinnig every icon, Restarting Explorer.exe, changing the taskbar-preferences...).
However, when checking the "Allways on top" option in the Task-Manager, the taskbar disappears while playing! This leads me to the assumption that the JPanel somehow keeps the taskbar in focus, while the taskmanager doesn't.
Does someone know what causes this issue?

Some more information that might be relevant:
-The game got an update a few days ago
-I was using Classic Shell all the time
-Windows got an update that forced me to reinstall Classic Shell

I know, my problem does not sound that terrible, but I'm recording my custom gamemodes for Youtube and the taskbar is really annoying.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This: `textArea_Messages.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));` is "a" issue, Swing doesn't know how to components with render alpha based colors, as it only knows how to deal with opaque or transparent colors, you should try making the `JTextArea` transparent (using `setOpaque`) as well

Comment: Thanks! Changed it but of course, this doesn't fix the issue with my taskbar....